# Numpy advanced indexing usage

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

**Case 1 (solved):** Array A has shape (say) (300,50). Array B is an indices array with the shape (300,5), such that `B[i,j]` indicate for the row `i` the index of another row to "concate" next to the row `i`. The end result is an array C with the shape (300,5,50), such that `C[i,j,:] = A[B[i,j],:]`. This can be done by calling `A[B,:]`.

Here is small script example for case 1:

```
import numpy as np

## A is the data array
A = np.arange(20).reshape((5,4))
## B indicate for each row which rows to pull together
B = np.array([[0,2],[1,2],[2,0],[3,4],[4,1]])
A[B,:] #The desired result
```

**Case 2 (unsolved):** Same problem, only now A is shaped (100,300,50). If B is the indicies matrix shaped (100,300,5), the end result would be an array C with the shape (100,300,5,50) such that `C[i,j,k,:] = A[i,B[i,j,k],:]`. `A[B,:]` doesn't work anymore, because it result with a shape (100,300,5,300,50), due to broadcasting.

How should I approach this with indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be reshaping to `2D` keeping the number of columns intact and then indexing into the first axis with the flattened `B` indices and finally reshaping back to the desired one.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
A.reshape(-1,A.shape[-1])[B.ravel()].reshape(100,300,5,50)
```

Those reshaping being merely views into the arrays, should be quite efficient.

This solves both cases. Here's a sample run for the case #1 -

1) Inputs :

```
In [667]: A = np.random.rand(3,4)
     ...: B = np.random.randint(0,3,(3,5))
     ...:
```

2) Original method :

```
In [668]: A[B,:]
Out[668]: 
array([[[ 0.1 ,  0.91,  0.1 ,  0.98],
        [ 0.1 ,  0.91,  0.1 ,  0.98],
        [ 0.1 ,  0.91,  0.1 ,  0.98],
        [ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02],
        [ 0.1 ,  0.91,  0.1 ,  0.98]],

       [[ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02],
        [ 0.48,  0.6 ,  0.96,  0.21],
        [ 0.48,  0.6 ,  0.96,  0.21],
        [ 0.1 ,  0.91,  0.1 ,  0.98],
        [ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02]],

       [[ 0.48,  0.6 ,  0.96,  0.21],
        [ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02],
        [ 0.48,  0.6 ,  0.96,  0.21],
        [ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02],
        [ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02]]])
```

3) Proposed method :

```
In [669]: A.reshape(-1,A.shape[-1])[B.ravel()].reshape(3,5,4)
Out[669]: 
array([[[ 0.1 ,  0.91,  0.1 ,  0.98],
        [ 0.1 ,  0.91,  0.1 ,  0.98],
        [ 0.1 ,  0.91,  0.1 ,  0.98],
        [ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02],
        [ 0.1 ,  0.91,  0.1 ,  0.98]],

       [[ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02],
        [ 0.48,  0.6 ,  0.96,  0.21],
        [ 0.48,  0.6 ,  0.96,  0.21],
        [ 0.1 ,  0.91,  0.1 ,  0.98],
        [ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02]],

       [[ 0.48,  0.6 ,  0.96,  0.21],
        [ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02],
        [ 0.48,  0.6 ,  0.96,  0.21],
        [ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02],
        [ 0.45,  0.16,  0.02,  0.02]]])
```

Comment: Wonderful! Case 2 needs a modification, since the indicies represent a relative location, thus required to be moved to globally when you flatten them. What I've done is to do: `B_new = B+(B.shape[1]*np.arange(B.shape[0]))[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]`. But this trick solved my problem! Thanks.